# Is it possible to map External Content Type to Office Item Type without using SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, external-contenttype

I need to connect Outlook to the External list and have to map its content type to the Office Item Type for that, but unfortunately I can't see it in SPD2013. Possibly it is because BDC model uses OData, which has limited support in SPD2013 ([my question about it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52555/external-content-type-based-on-odata-is-invisible-in-spd2013-but-visible-in-a-w)).

**So, is it possible to map External Content Type to Office Item Type without using SharePoint Designer? If so, how can I do it?**

Thank you in advance.

PS: SharePoint 2013 RTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurray! 
After three days of unsuccessful googling and asking this question everywhere :-) I tried to investigate it myself and at last, I have found a way to do it!

It appeared that it is quite easy to map it by hand. For that you have to make 2 changes in the BDC model file (xml with a .bdcm extension):

**Add property with the name of Office item type to the entity**

```
<Entities>
    <Entity Name="AbsenceCalendar" DefaultDisplayName="AbsenceCalendar"  Namespace="MyNameSpace" Version="1.0.0.0" EstimatedInstanceCount="2000">
<Properties>
    <Property Name="OutlookItemType" Type="System.String">Appointment</Property>
    ...
</Properties>
...
```

**Map necessary fields to the Office Item Type.** For instance, for mandatory fields of Appointment Office Item Type it could look like

```
<Method Name="ReadSpecificAbsenceCalendarEntity" DefaultDisplayName="Read Specific AbsenceCalendarEntity" IsStatic="false">    
......    
  <Parameter Name="@AbsenceCalendarEntity" Direction="Return">
     <TypeDescriptor Name="AbsenceCalendarEntity" DefaultDisplayName="AbsenceCalendarEntity" TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType">   
       <TypeDescriptors> 
           <TypeDescriptor Name="Title" DefaultDisplayName="Title" TypeName="System.String"> 
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="OfficeProperty" Type="System.String">Subject</Property>
              </Properties>
           </TypeDescriptor>
           <TypeDescriptor Name="StartDate" DefaultDisplayName="StartDate" TypeName="System.DateTime">
              <Properties>
                 <Property Name="OfficeProperty" Type="System.String">Start</Property>
               </Properties>
            </TypeDescriptor>
            <TypeDescriptor Name="EndDate" DefaultDisplayName="EndDate" TypeName="System.DateTime">
                <Properties>
                       <Property Name="OfficeProperty" Type="System.String">End</Property>
                 </Properties>
            </TypeDescriptor>
.......
```